# crawler by using urls

Tags: python, url

Hi evry one i need to crawl a sit by using python(my python version is 2.6.6) only using urls.

- first i need to open this link(http://www.google.com/) and crawl,and i should collect all http links which are present in this page;
- second, from the collected http links,i should go to each and every link, through this link i need to open  and do the crawling  process and should save the crawled links in a separate folder.
  iam just trying in this way,if any one is know the solution plz reply i need your help..

Answer (score 2):

Step1: Use `urllib or urllib2` library of python and visit your page.

Step2: Use any xml/html parser like [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to fetch all the links from your web page.

Step3: Now again pass these links to urllib or urllib2 and save your webpage.

And you can also give [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) or [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) a try.

And here is an example of using `xpath expressions with lxml`. You can get the xpath of any element using `firebug`.

```
import lxml
from lxml import etree
import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen('your url')
html = response.read()
link = etree.HTML(html)
links = link.xpath('xpath expr')
```

Comment: i collected all the http links for the first step,but iam unable to click each and every link and crawl from which i was collected this process is for many links...

Comment: ok.I understood till `unable to click each and every link` but after that its a little unclear

Comment: And tell me the exact problem you are facing.

Comment: my problem is using that collected links for each and every link i need to click it and i need to go to that next page and crawl that page,iam unable to click the link from which i was collected

Comment: exact is using that links i need to go to that page...

Comment: ok,so you got all the links and than you have to use each link to crawl the webpage it is pointing to. Lets suppose you have list of all links `myl=[link1,link2,link3]`. here `link1,2,3` are the links you collected from webpage, now use `urllib` class and pass these links to it.

Comment: `for m in myl: data = urllib.urlopen(m).read()`

Comment: the above was my program but for stmt is not working.is this the correct way to give.

Comment: I think you are trying to iterate over a dictionary. But you are not doing it correctly. So,take a look here http://www.littletechtips.com/2009/10/python-101-how-to-iterate.html

Comment: if you are sure that you have correctly used `Beautiful soup & httplib` module, than take a look here http://pastebin.com/VGNe8G7a

Comment: I have made some changes to your code. I am not sure if they will work correctly because i don't have beautiful soup and httplib installed on my pc. But you will get a general of iterating dictionary.

Comment: check one more thing that url are starting with `google.com` and not with `http://` or something else

Comment: Thanks for ur advice,i got the output.